What is the current way (2024) to install and let run the Yi (Haskell) text editor?
Yi project seems asleep since 2017. On https://github.com/yi-editor/yi, [not so] recent problem reports remain unanswered. During that time ghc tools and hackage content keep evolve. Latest questions here on this topic seem to be ten years old.
However, it doesn't seem completely foolish to build this editor using legacy versions of ghc and dependance packages.
Did anyone recently achieve that goal? And how?
Platform: macOS (probably not so relevant, success on any *nix/posix will make us happy).
Among several tries:

At the time of writing, using up to date ghc and packages leans to what is described in https://github.com/yi-editor/yi/issues/1135.
cabal install yi --with-compiler=ghc-8.10.7 fails with errors on the exported modules by vty.
cabal install yi --with-compiler=ghc-8.10.7 --constraint 'vty < 6.0' fails on other vty troubles.
stack install inside a directory containing a cloned github repository also fails.


It is packaged in nixpkgs, so if you have the Nix package manager, you can install it right away.

I opened https://github.com/yi-editor/yi/pull/1136 to fix most of the problems of making it work with modern dependencies, which is now merged. Make sure you have alex 3.2.7.1 or newer (specifying such a constraint on the command line doesn't appear to be working for some reason), then check out the repo and cabal build all --allow-newer -c 'vty<6' and cabal install yi --allow-newer -c 'vty<6' should both work.
